# Audiotrack (for video) - workflow from Ableton Live to Adobe Premiere

Tags: video, audio, software, sync

I'm creating audio in Ableton Live that will be muxed with edited video footage in Adobe Premiere. The audio is everything from (Foley) effects to background music, and it must be in sync with events in the video. I can think of (at least) two methods of merging and syncing audio and video:

1. Create the complete multilayered audio in Live's arrangement view, carefully timing audio-effects to the timing of the respective video events, and exporting the merged audio-layers as a single wav-file for import as a single audiotrack in Premiere.
2. Export each audio-effect in its own wav-file from Live, and do the layering and timing of the different audio clips (on multiple audio tracks) in Premiere.

I think method 2 gives more flexibility with regards to further video editing; if a video segment is cut out, it's easier to just move the subsequent audio clips along the timeline and thereby maintaining video-audio-sync, as opposed to going back to Live and manually re-sync the audio for another export to Premiere.

I'm wondering: Are there other advantages/disadvantages between the two workflows? Are there other, smarter workflows to consider?

Comment: I had a similar question here: http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/4775/what-to-fix-first-audio-or-video I first made a rough cut of my video with approximate transitions, then imported that video in Live and started the sound design. With the video playing in Live I could see where and what sort of sound I would want. After making the soundtrack in Live (I only had background music, no Foley) I exported it to Premiere and then cut my video exactly to the right transitions. It was a timelapse, so I could play with the duration of each clip easily. But with Foley, I would go for no. 2

Comment: @BartArondson Thank you for a useful comment! I too think it depends a little on the characteristic of the video, making the choice a little different for a timelapse. I understand Live only accepts QuickTime-video?

Comment: Not sure, I've done two small projects this way and both times I used a Quicktime video. Good luck, and if your work is public I would be interested in seeing it, please post a link.